# How to use spark with large decimal numbers?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, types

My database has `numeric` value, which is up to 256-bit unsigned integer. However, spark's `decimalType` has a limit of Decimal(38,18).

When I try to do calculations on the column, exceptions are thrown.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Decimal precision 39 exceeds max precision 38".

Is there any third-party library or workarounds that solve this issue? Or Spark is designed for numbers smaller than Decimal(38,18)?

Answer (score 1):

If you must store as numeric type:

- `cast(value as Double)` (possible loss of precision)
- `cast(value as Decimal(38, 18))` (possible overflow)

If your data doesn't need to be involved in the calculation, you can transform them to `String`.